# Swift WKWebView handle credential popups

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, alert, wkwebview

I'm working on a Secure Web Browser `iOS` App. I'm using `Swift` for development.

My app have a `WKWebView` for loading URLs. When I'm loading this URL http://relaw.wpengine.com on my App. `WKWebView` is not showing Credentials Popup.

I have already implemented `WKUIDelegate` methods

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
 }

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
 }

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
}
```

But, they don't handle this credentials popup.

How can I handle these type of popups in `WKWebView`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an implementation for the `webView(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)` method on `WKNavigationDelegate`. This method is called when the webView receives an authentication challenge.

See this reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455638-webview

Comment: Thanks Dave :-) keep coding

Comment: No problem! \o/

Comment: I have tried, tried, tried , tried....and it won't work!!!!! :/ here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772487/how-to-use-wkwebview-for-user-authentication

Comment: @DaveWeston I have just added a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772487/how-to-use-wkwebview-for-user-authentication . Check the link.