# How to use WKWebView for user authentication?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swift

**Goal**: Retrieve accessToken and user details without using any of the native controls to enter user credentials. Use SSO login for same.

**Steps**: iOS App and user perform

1.User chooses SSO Login option

2.User redirects to SSO Login URL

3.SSO Login URL shows an JavaScript Alert to input username and
    password.(On desktop and mobile browsers, it doesn't show anything
    in webview)

4.Once the user enters the credentials, he is redirected to our server, which returns html page with user data.

**What I have tried:**
Tried using following

```
func viewDidLoad(){
        let pref = WKPreferences()
        pref.javaScriptEnabled = true
        pref.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true

        /* Create a config using pref*/
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = pref

        /* Instantiate the web view */

        let webviewFrame = CGRect(x:0,y: txtSSOLoginUrl.bounds.maxY, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height - 40)
        webView = WKWebView(frame:webviewFrame,configuration: configuration)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate  = self
        webView.load(request as URLRequest)
}

extension SSOLoginViewController:WKUIDelegate,WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        print("DID START NAV didStartProvisionalNavigation")

    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("RECEIVERD SERVER REDIRECT")

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("EERRORRR : \(error)")
    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print ("ERRRRRR : \(error)")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler()
        }))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        print("runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessages")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        print("runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = defaultText
        }
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
                completionHandler(text)
            } else {
                completionHandler(defaultText)
            }

        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            completionHandler(nil)

        }))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        print("DID FINISH NAV didFinish navigation")

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        print("DECIDE POLICY WKNavigationResponse \(navigationResponse)")
        decisionHandler(.allow)

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        print("DID RECEIVE URLAuthenticationChallenge")
         //var cred = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "Password123!", persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.none)
         //challenge.sender?.use(password, for: challenge)
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, nil)

    }
 }
```

**Output**
Not seeing alert asking user credentials.

**Expected Output**
Get an alert with username and password textfields to input credentials.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: SFSafariViewController doesn't work. Tried it.

Comment: any solution to this problem till date ?

Comment: Did this issue was resolved. Can you please help i am having the same issue.

Comment: Nope, but we then did it in a different way, we created a server page which our server redirected to after it handled the SSO auth and we just read the required details from the hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

What we did to get around this problem was, we used an HTML page which was served by the server and the backend did the actual redirection with required details in the hidden field. That redirect URL was given to the other party which used their own SSO login, but through our app, inside a web view. This is not a solution to the problem but a workaround. Never actually got to solve this issue.